# How to do transitions on opacity in compass?

Tags: compass-sass

We have excellent mixins for opacity and transitions in compass, but how can I do a transition on opacity?

```
@include single-transition(opacity, 1s);
```

Above line creates a transition on opacity, but not on -moz-opacity, -khtml-opacity, let alone the weird IE syntaxes...

Comment: Apparently, it seems to work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the following code (but also the code you posted) creates the animation with all the required prefixes.

```
@include transition(opacity, 1s ease-out);
```

Where 1s is any amount of seconds (2s, 0.5s) and ease-out is any kind of easing animation (could be just linear if no parameter).

Comment: You're right, I did assume it didn't work, but it does.